# Вывести среднее количество просмотров всех постов на сайте

Tags: python, django

Есть модель страницы с полем views (IntegerField), нужно посчитать среднее арифметическое количества посещений для всех страниц в базе данных.

Я сделал так

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
views_all = 0
for post in posts:
    views_all += post.views
views_res = views_all/len(posts)
print(views_res)
```

Всё работает, но меня интересует, можно ли это сделать как-то по другому?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Django ORM есть функция Avg(). Ее можно использовать для вычисления среднего арифметического:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
from myapp.models import Post

views_res = Post.objects.aggregate(Avg('views'))['views__avg']
```

Здесь мы использовали метод `aggregate()` модели для вычисления среднего значения `views` по всем записям. `Avg('views')` указывает ORM вычислить среднее значение для поля `views`. Метод `aggregate()` возвращает словарь, в котором ключ 'views__avg' соответствует вычисленному среднему значению.

Думаю должно сработать.